# Posting data on haml form and put routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a show form and want to add a form to edit this so that a user can input a ticket id. I had initially amended this in the controller as an edit action but have since changed this to update. When i click on the submit button i get an error that says "No route matches [PUT]" and i feel a bit as though i may have missed a step somewhere.

edit.html.haml

```
= form_for [:admin, @diagnostic], url: edit_admin_diagnostic_path do |f|
    .field
        = label_tag :ticket_id
        = text_field_tag "ticket_id"
        = submit_tag "Submit", method: :put, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }

    .field
        = link_to 'show', admin_diagnostic_path
```

diagnostics_controller

```
class Admin::DiagnosticsController < Admin::BaseController

  before_filter :diagnostic, only: [:show, :delete, :edit, :update]

  def index
    @diagnostics = DiagnosticInfo.all.order_by(:created_at.desc).page(params[:page]).per(50)
  end

  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @diagnostic }
    end
  end

  def update
   @diagnostic = DiagnosticInfo.find(params[:id])
    if allowed.empty?
      render action: "edit", error: 'Un-allowed attribute update request!'
    elsif @diagnostic.update_attributes(allowed)
      redirect_to admin_lessons_url, notice: 'Lesson was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: "edit"
    end
  end


  end

  def destroy
    diagnostic.destroy
    redirect_to admin_diagnostics_path
  end
```

relevant part of routes.rb

```
  resources :diagnostics, only: [:index, :show, :destroy, :edit, :update] do 
      put 'ticket_id', on: :collection
    end
```

Comment: run `rake routes` It will list all your routes. It will be of better visibility into your routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know form argument should be:

```
= form_for [:admin, @diagnostic], url: admin_diagnostic_path(@diagnostic) do |f|
```

not `edit_admin_diagnostic_path`

`edit_admin_diagnostic_path` is going to `get` the edit page for admin_diagnostic while you are looking for `put`/`patch`

In your case you are trying to send `put` request to `.../edit` url which obviously doesn't exist hence this error.